# ties should not be present for the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

Tags: r

I find shape and scale using Weibull distribution.I want to use KS. For the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test, I got message

> ties should not be present for the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

How to solve it?

My code was

```
ks.test(data, "pweibull", shape = 1, scale = 7)
```

Comment: It's easier to help if you [make this question reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by including a small representative dataset in a plain text format - for example the output from `dput(data)`, if that is not too large.

Comment: Need to know the number of ties in contrast to the total number. Small proportion might not signal a problem.